# Windows 2008: Virtual file system(like FUSE)

Tags: windows, filesystems, fuse

I'm looking for virtual file system  for Windows like FUSE for Unix, Are there any suggestions for it? 
I've looked at [dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) , old port [fifs](http://web.mit.edu/fifs/www/) and also [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) but price of CFS is very huge. Thanks.

Comment: Sergii, the price of CBFS is negotiable. Please contact me privately as written in my profile.

Comment: The in-house private business license is at $2,511.00 or less is as of October 7, 2011 on the company site. I can't afford this. If you had a license closer to $100-300 dollars for a user to run linux fuse compatible filesystems or even make it free for open-source software, I might consider CBFS. If CBFS becomes a way to run some of the 40 or so linux fuse compatible fs, it will demonstrate that CBFS works.

Comment: @Fire are you stating that you can't afford "less"? :)

Comment: I'm saying I can't afford more than $200. If you want to me name a price I want it to be $50.

Comment: @Fire we have free non-commercial licenses now as well.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/a/1428914/4060 - newer answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of investigation I decided to try  Callback File System in trial mode and will see ...

Comment: If you finally managed to get something out of CBFS: did it work as expected ? Would you recommend it ?

Answer (score 1):

you can to use boxedapp in your case.
Thanks.

Comment: +1 great appliucation. it helped me.