# Create fake storage device

Tags: windows, filesystems, storage

Is it possible to create a fake storage device by software?

I want a similar behavior like a usb stick. It should appear in the filesystem. If I put some data in it, the driver should push it over network.

Is that behavior generally possible?

I want to do that for Windows and Mac OS.

Comment: `net use \\server\share`

Comment: @tenfour: Good point - using existing network filesystems might be sufficient (or not), depending on the requirements.

Comment: I do not want to use another server. Let's say I do not want to push the data - this driver only manages the data or it just anything about it.

Comment: See also [Windows 2008: Virtual file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689048/windows-2008-virtual-file-systemlike-fuse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is called a [Virtual File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system), and it's indeed possible. See e.g. this article for an example of making one: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Programming_a_Virtual_File_System-Part_I.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You need a virtual disk or a virtual file system. Note that "Virtual File System" can be used to define a file system kept not on physical media or it can be used to define a "gateway" between the OS and some non-FS data (such as a database).

Our company offers [Virtual Storage](http://www.eldos.com/virtual-storage/) line of products that let you create virtual disks and filesystems on Windows.

As for MacOS X - there exists free [Fuse4X](http://fuse4x.org/) product for Macs. This is a fork of now-obsolete MacFUSE.